# Convert a summer date to utc in the winter?

Tags: c, time, utc, dst

The function `mktime` takes a `struct tm` as argument.  One of the members of `struct tm` is `tm_isdst`. You can set this to 1 for wintertime, 0 for summertime, or -1 if you don't know.

However, if during winter, you try to convert `2009-09-01 00:00`, `mktime` fails to see that although it is currently winter, the date you are converting is summertime.  So the result is one hour off.  For me (GMT+1) it's `2009-08-31 22:00`, while it should be `23:00`.

Is there a way to determine if a particular date is in the summer or wintertime period?  Is it possible to convert a summer date to utc in the winter?

(I hit upon this problem trying to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764710/converting-string-containing-localtime-into-utc-in-c))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of the (many) [deficiencies](http://david.tribble.com/text/c0xlongtime.html) in the [time](http://david.tribble.com/text/c0xcalendar.html) handling [interfaces](http://david.tribble.com/text/c0xtimezone.html) in Standard C.  See also the [Olson](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) time zone database.  There isn't an easy way to find when a time zone switches between winter and summer (daylight saving and standard) time, for example.  Anything in the future is, of course, a prediction — the rule sets change often (the current release is [2017a](ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz/releases/tzdata2017a.tar.gz)).

> Is there as far as you know, a UNIX specific solution?

I took a look at the code in tzcode2017a.tar.gz, and the `mktime()` there behaves as you want if you set the tm_isdst to -1 (unknown).  So, if you use that (public domain) code, you would be OK - probably.  Quoting from 'localtime(3)' as distributed with the Olson code:

> Mktime converts the broken‐down time, expressed as local time, in the structure pointed to by tm into a calendar time value with the same encoding as that of the values returned by the time function. The original values of the `tm_wday` and `tm_yday` components of the structure are ignored, and the original values of the other components are not restricted  to their normal ranges. (A positive or zero value for `tm_isdst` causes `mktime` to presume initially that summer time (for example, Daylight Saving Time in the U.S.A.) respectively, is or is not in effect for the specified time.  A negative value for `tm_isdst` causes the `mktime` function to attempt to divine whether summer time is in effect for the specified time; in this case it does not use a consistent rule and may give a different answer when later presented with the same argument.)

I believe that the last caveat about a 'consistent rule' means that if the specification of the time zone changes (for example, as when the USA changed from 1st week in April to 2nd week in March for the change to Daylight Saving Time) mean that if you determined some time before the rule changed and after the rule changed, the same input data would give different outputs.

(Note there are useful HTML files in ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz/ directory, such as ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz/tz-link.html.)

Comment: +1 Interesting.  Is there as far as you know, a UNIX specific solution?