# Int32 to Epoch to readable data?! [C]

Tags: c

Ok, so, I have this function here that actually DOES work, but i don't get it.

Why does it work like this:

```
void timeToData(unsigned __int32 timeH)
{
     struct tm *newtime;
     time_t long_time = timeH;
     newtime = localtime(&long_time);
     printf("%s\n", asctime(newtime));  
}
```

And not like this?

```
void timeToData(unsigned __int32 timeH)
{
     struct tm newtime;
     newtime = timeH;
     printf("%s\n", asctime(newtime));  
}
```

Comment: See related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076494/how-to-convert-from-utc-to-local-time-in-c, that can be useful in that case.

Comment: What is it about the function that confuses or surprises you?

Comment: Everything you need to know can be found here: https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your non-working version attempts to assign a value of numeric type to an object of type `struct tm`:

```
     struct tm newtime;
     newtime = timeH;
```

No behavior is defined for such assignments, and its not clear what behavior could be expected other than outright rejection of the code.  When it does reject that code, surely your compiler emits a diagnostic that explains that it has done so because of incompatible operands of the `=` operator.

Your non-working version also attempts to pass an argument of type `struct tm` to function `asctime()`, which expects instead a *pointer* to such a structure:

```
    printf("%s\n", asctime(newtime));
```

Structures and pointers to them are not interchangeable.  Your compiler may diagnose this, too, emitting one or more additional error messages about incompatible types.

Now let's consider the working version.  I note first that local variable `newtime` is declared differently in that version, as a *pointer* to a `struct tm`:

```
    struct tm *newtime;
```

That takes care of the second issue above.  I furthermore note that `struct tm *` is also the type returned by the `localtime()` function, so the assignment of that function's result to that `newtime` is perfectly fine.

From there, we observe that the argument to `localtime` must have type `time_t *`, which is exactly the type of the expression `&long_time`, given that `long_time` itself is a `time_t`.

So the only remaining point of possible confusion that I see revolves around the assignment of `timeH`, an `unsigned __int32`, to variable `long_time`.  Unless some nasty obfuscation is going on, however, `unsigned __int32` is an integer type.  The standard tells us, furthermore, that `time_t` is a "real [type] capable of representing times" (C2011, [paragraph 7.27.1/3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.1p3)).  In that context, "real" has a meaning based on mathematical usage of that term; overall, it's saying that `time_t` is a *numeric* type with no imaginary component -- *i.e.* that the values it can represent form a subset of the real numbers.

Exactly what type `time_t` is is not specified, but C broadly permits assignments between different numeric types, with few caveats or restrictions.  Thus, even though we don't know exactly what type `time_t` is, there's no particular reason to suppose that the assignment would be invalid.  As a quality of implementation issue, it is not surprising that the assignment is value-preserving (which is demonstrated in practice by the fact that the function works).