# How to get the difference of timestamps with millisecond resolution?

Tags: c, linux, time, difference

I need to find the difference of 2 time stamps having format `YYYY DD MM HH MM SS MSC`. For example, the difference of `2022 08 13 08 17 20 512` and `2022 08 13 08 17 20 000` should return `512 msec`.

I have gone through the posts in [How to convert from UTC to local time in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076494/how-to-convert-from-utc-to-local-time-in-c).

`mktime` using `struct tm pointer` has a provision to represent till seconds resolution. Which function should we use to include milliseconds portion as well for computation?

Comment: `2 time stamps having format`  In what timezone are the timestamps? `has provision to represent till seconds resolution.` soooo handle seconds and milliseconds yourself? I do not understand. `Which function should we use to include milliseconds portion as well for computation ?` Write one yourself? After `mktime` it's just `seconds * 1000 + milliseconds`. `How to get the difference of time stamps having milliseconds portion using C in Linux?` Represent the time in milliseconds. Subtract.

Comment: @KamilCuk the timestamps are in UTC time zone. I was thinking if any system function is already available, i can use them.

Comment: `are in UTC time zone` So remember to set timezone before calling `mktime`. `I was thinking if any system function is already available` There is none. With glibc there is `timersub` for `struct timeval`. There's also better `struct timespec`, but no functions I know of.

Comment: For Linux (especially if you're writing normal software and can't reconfigure the OS or kernel to suit yourself); you can expect that all your hopes and dreams will be destroyed as soon as you expect anything to work properly for leap seconds.

Answer (score 0):

C provides `difftime` to figure out the number of seconds and `timegm` is helpful for the UTC timezone. Watch out for that tricky `tm_mon` element (number of months since January, so August is really 7 not 8).

Maybe extend on the result from `difftime` by adding the msec difference?

Something like this?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct TIME {
  struct tm tm;
  unsigned int tm_msec;
};

double difftime_ms( struct TIME *time2, struct TIME *time1 )
{
  time_t t1 = timegm( &time1->tm );
  time_t t2 = timegm( &time2->tm );
  return ( 1000.0 * difftime( t2, t1 ) + ( time2->tm_msec - time1->tm_msec ) );
}

int main()
{
  struct TIME time1 = { .tm = { .tm_year = 2022, .tm_mon = (8-1), .tm_mday = 13, .tm_hour = 8, .tm_min = 17, .tm_sec = 20} , .tm_msec = 000 };
  struct TIME time2 = { .tm = { .tm_year = 2022, .tm_mon = (8-1), .tm_mday = 13, .tm_hour = 8, .tm_min = 17, .tm_sec = 20} , .tm_msec = 512 };

  printf( "Difference is %.2f msec\n", difftime_ms( &time2, &time1 ) );
  return 0;
}
```